# .next() method not found in `std::string::String`

Tags: parsing, rust, readfile

I have a file containing something like:

```
144NFFFFL
```

I would like to be able to read each character and always converting the first 3 to an integer (i32) by parsing them. For some reason my `.next()` call does not compile.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut test = Robot::new(0, 3, 4, Orientation::N, vec![Direction::F, Direction::F]);
    println!("id = {:#?} , x = {:#?} , y = {:#?} , ori = {:#?} , dir = {:#?} ,",test.id,test.x,test.y,test.orientation,test.direction);

    let mut file = File::open("instruction.txt").expect("Impossible d'ouvrire le fichier"); //ouverture du fichier instruction.txt et le stock dans la var mut
    let mut contenue = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut contenue).expect("Impossible de lire le fichier");
    contenue = line!(.split_whitespace()).to_string();
    
    let mut tmp = (contenue.next()).to_string();
    test.id = tmp.parse::<i32>().unwarp();

    tmp = (contenue.next()).to_string();
    test.x = tmp.parse::<i32>().unwarp();

    tmp = (contenue.next()).to_string();
    test.y = tmp.parse::<i32>().unwarp();

    tmp = contenue.next();
    test.orientation = tmp;
}
```

the error =>

```
let mut tmp = (contenue.next()).to_string();
    |                             ^^^^ method not found in `std::string::String`

error[E0599]: no method named `next` found for struct `std::string::String` in the current scope
   --> src/main.rs:120:21
    |
120 |     tmp = (contenue.next()).to_string();
    |                     ^^^^ method not found in `std::string::String`

error[E0599]: no method named `next` found for struct `std::string::String` in the current scope
   --> src/main.rs:123:21
    |
123 |     tmp = (contenue.next()).to_string();
    |                     ^^^^ method not found in `std::string::String`

error[E0599]: no method named `next` found for struct `std::string::String` in the current scope
   --> src/main.rs:126:20
    |
126 |     tmp = contenue.next();
    |                    ^^^^ method not found in `std::string::String`

error[E0599]: no method named `next` found for struct `std::string::String` in the current scope
   --> src/main.rs:131:36
    |
131 |         let carac = match contenue.next()
    |                                    ^^^^ method not found in `std::string::String
```

Comment: `to_string()` not found in `std::string::String` says to me you already got a string ;)

Comment: Should `test.id` be `144` or `49`? And what should `test.x` and `test.y` be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next()` is an [iterator method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next). To use it, you need an iterator for your String. Usually that's [`chars()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars).

```
let iter = contenue.chars();
```

Once you have an iterator of characters, you can iterate through only the first 3 characters with [`take(3)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take). Then use `collect()` to join them together into a string. Then `parse` it.

```
let id: u32 = iter
    .take(3)
    .collect::<String>()
    .parse::<u32>()
    .unwrap();
println!("ID = {}", id);
```

Since this is an iterator it will remember its position. The next call to `iter.next()` will be `N`. So we could print out the rest of the characters.

```
for c in iter {
    println!("c = {}", c);
}
```

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `iter`
  --> test.rs:12:14
   |
3  |     let iter = contenue.chars();
   |         ---- move occurs because `iter` has type `std::str::Chars<'_>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
4  |     
5  |     let id: u32 = iter
   |                   ---- value moved here
...
12 |     for c in iter {
   |              ^^^^ value used here after move
```

The problem is `iter.take()` took ownership of the iterator. We need to use [`by_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.by_ref) to borrow it. And we need to make the iterator mutable.

```
fn main() { 
    let contenue = "144NFFFFL";
    let mut iter = contenue.chars();
    
    let id: u32 = iter
        .by_ref()
        .take(3)
        .collect::<String>()
        .parse::<u32>()
        .unwrap();
    println!("ID = {}", id);   
    
    for c in iter {
        println!("c = {}", c);
    } 
}
```